# Varchar to Number in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to convert data type for a column from Varchar to Number but I was not successful.

tried below functions:
try_to_number
cast (col as number(38,0))

[image]

Comment: `but I was not successful` what exactly mean? do you get an error? or what?

Comment: I am getting null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe because of commas , try this :

```
select try_to_number(replace(sentcount,','))
```

Comment: Yes, commas were creating the issue.